# Как получить год и неделю по стандарту ISO 8601?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, стандарт, iso

Есть код ниже, который выводит строку содержащую год/неделю `202153`. Но нужно, чтобы вместо первой недели 2021 года, была последняя неделя 2020 года, то есть года ISO.

Есть ли встроенная функция для решения этой проблемы?

```
SELECT to_char(to_date('20210104', 'YYYYMMDD') - 3, 'YYYYIW') AS yearweek
FROM dual;

YEARWE
------
202153
```

Ожидаемый вывод: `202053`.

Конечно, можно просто применить `decode`, но надеюсь, что есть более удачное решение.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [ISO Week 202153](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67318299) от участника [@jeiv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15746603/jeiv)</sub>

---

Полезный [комментарий](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67318299/oracle-sql-iso-week-202153#comment118999010_67318299):
Может стоит использовать официальный формат согласно ISO-8601:

```
TO_CHAR(..., 'IYYY "W "IW')
```

, чтобы избежать двусмысленного формата `YYYYMM` - Wernfried Domscheit

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/67318299

Answer (score 3):

Надо использвоать [маску формата](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A) `IYYY` (ISO год) вместо `YYYY` (календарный год):

```sql
select to_char (date'2021-01-04' - 3, 'IYYYIW') yearweek
from dual
/

YEARWEEK
--------
202053
```